# cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue() when value is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, null

i would think this is simple but is there a way of using Isnull(field,[something]) when value is null?

```
/*************Connectionstring is located in Web.config ******************/
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

/*************Exec stored Procedure from tblActivity ******************/
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_tblActivity", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", txtActivity.Text); // , Isnull(txtActivity.text, *changetosomething*)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", txtComment.Text);
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    BindGridviewActivity();


}
```

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", isnull(txtActivity.Text, ***[dosomething]***)` is this possible to do insted of using a if() statement in the begining?

Comment: The `Text`-Property of a `TextBox` is probably `string.Empty` instead of `null`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you should probably [move away from using AddWithValue() in the first place.](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Setting that aside for the moment, you're looking at a Control's `Text` property. Something has to go really wrong for a `Text` property to ever result in `null`. You probably just need to check if it's empty (or maybe only has whitespace) instead:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtActivity.Text) ? "change to something" : txtActivity.Text);
```

But maybe you want to send an actual SQL `NULL` to the database. SQL `NULL` is different from a C#/.Net `null`. In that case, you could do this:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtActivity.Text) ? DBNull.Value : txtActivity.Text);
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a method extension for DBNULL...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static SqlParameter AddWithNullValue(this SqlParameterCollection collection, string parameterName, object value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, DBNull.Value);
        else
            return collection.AddWithValue(parameterName, value);
    }

}
```

So...instead of using AddWithValue....you would use AddWithNullValue

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator):

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Activity", txtActivity.Text ?? "something else");
```